# Angular 11- but data ['id'] is underlined in red in this section. How can I do this?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to reach the id in the form and after adding, the details of the added record should be displayed.

```
  add(city:City)
  {

    this.httpClient.post(this.path+'cities/add',city).subscribe(data=>{
      this.alertifyService.success("Şehir Başarayla Eklendi.");
      this.router.navigateByUrl('cityDetail/'+data['id']);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add response type to post function

```js
add(city:City) {
  this.httpClient.post<{id: string>}(this.path+'cities/add',city).subscribe(data=>{
    this.alertifyService.success("Şehir Başarayla Eklendi.");
    this.router.navigateByUrl('cityDetail/'+data['id']);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new to Angular and Typescript. You helped me a lot. I've been trying to solve the problem for hours. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the full functionality of `typescript` here, and that's why you aren't able to reach the `id` property. Anytime you can, define the type of arguments, responses, invocations and returns.

In your specific case, you forgot to tell angular how will the response of this `post` be. In other words, what specific type of data will you receive. In order to do that, you can use the typescript [`type assertion`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), and do something like:

*Of course, the properties and their type I added to the post are just examples.*

```js
this.httpClient.post<{
    prop1: string;
    prop2: boolean;
    id: number
}>(this.path + 'cities/add', city)
```